# Creating a generic JavaBean builder

Tags: java, generics, reflection, builder

I'm trying to create a generic builder for value classes. You know those dumb classes full of getter and setters.

The goal is to be able to use it like this:

```
        MyValueObject myvalueObject = new GenericBuilder<MyValueObject>(MyValueObject.class)
            .with("someIntegerProperty", 12)
            .build();
```

Here's my attempt so far using reflection:

```
public class GenericBuilder<T> {
    private T bean;
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public GenericBuilder(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;

        Constructor<?> constructor = null;
        try {
            constructor = Class.forName(clazz.getCanonicalName()).getConstructor();
            bean = (T) constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public <S> GenericBuilder<T> with(String propertyName, S value) {
        Method method;
        try {
            method = Class.forName(clazz.getCanonicalName())
                .getMethod("set" + propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1), Object.class);
            method.invoke(bean, (S) value);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }

    public T build() {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

However the method invocation fails with a `NoSuchMethodException` because the determined parameter type at runtime is `Object` instead of the correct type. <strike>This is due to type erasure</strike>.

I know that I can get the actual parameter type with `method.getParameterTypes()[0]`, but I cannot use it to cast the `value` like this

```
method.invoke(bean, (method.getParameterTypes()[0]) value); //compiler error
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is builder method easier than this?

Comment: Please take a look at [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) before you continue.

Comment: Honestly, one `@Builder` from lombok will free you from this problem. It's compact, concise and type-safe.

Comment: @lexicore I might not be able to change the value classes. And there are several skeptics on using Lombok on my team.

Comment: @inovaovao And they at the same time are not sceptics of your reflection-based generic builder approach?

Comment: @lexicore I haven't pushed yet ;-) And this is to simplify test code.

Comment: @inovaovao Your approach is unsafe and error-prone. You drop type safety and comiler checks on properties. That's a road to hell if you will ever need to refactor any of your beans. Don't do this.

Comment: @lexicore Good point. Well then I'm still interested in the answer as an academic exercise :-)

Comment: @inovaovao You simply search for a method with the appropriate name and a single parameter of type which could accept your `S value`.

Comment: @inovaovao Also why do you constantly do `Class.forName(clazz.getCanonicalName())`? Why not just use `clazz`?

Comment: @inovaovao Just check how `BeanUtils.setProperty` is implemented in [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/). It's not quite trivial to do correctly. Type conversions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resorted to looping through the method names and just checking that there is actually only one parameter. This is of course not very safe, but it works for my tests.

Here's the new `with(String propertyName, S value)` method implementation:

```
public <S> GenericBuilder<T> with(String propertyName, S value) {
    try {
        String target = "set" + propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + propertyName.substring(1);
        for (Method m : clazz.getMethods()) {
            if (target.equals(m.getName())) {
                Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
                if (params.length == 1) {
                    m.invoke(bean, value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this;
}
```